# Fixing Check-boxes while validating inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the piece of code which is troubling now

```
if(!IsActive) {
        IsActive = true;
        $('#Submit').prop('disabled', true);

        var icheckBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
        for(var i=0; i < icheckBoxes.length; i++) {
            if(!icheckBoxes.eq(i).is(":checked")) { 
                $('.checkbox'+i).css('color','#ff0000');
            }
            IsActive = false;
            $('#Submit').prop('disabled', false);   
        }

        var sture = $('#sture').val().trim();

        if (sture.length < 3) {         
            $('#sture').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');   
            var errormsg = "Check the Page";

            swal('',errormsg,'warning');    
            IsActive = false;
            $('#Submit').prop('disabled', false);           
            return false;
        }

        swal({
              title: "Processing",
              text: "",
              html: true,
              showCancelButton:false,
              showConfirmButton:false,
              allowOutsideClick:false
        }); 

        var values = $('#Form').serialize();
        $.post('/processing/page.html', values, function(data){
            if ( data.status == 1) {

            } 
            else { 

                IsActive = false;
                $('#Submit').prop('disabled', false);
                return false;
            }
        },"JSON");      
    }
```

now it should basically highlight all the checkboxes text if none is checked and stop the processing of the page, but it just stops on the first one and makes it read and then never moves forward.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Remove the `return false;`. Also note that you can use an `each()` loop to tidy the code, instead of a `for` loop

Comment: `return false;` will stop the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Why do you have a return at all?

Comment: after this validation, there is another piece which validates a submit button but that is separate so i am not sure how it is going to behave, I updated my code please check

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `opacity` css property, try it

```js
function highlight() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
     if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    } else {
      $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
    }
  });
}

setInterval(() => highlight(), 1500);
```

```css
.checkbox1,
.checkbox2,
.checkbox3,
.checkbox4 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox4" />
```

---

And here the version with `$.each()` which is simplier to read

```js
function highlight() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    } else {
      $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
    }
  });
}

setInterval(() => highlight(), 1500);
```

```css
.checkbox1,
.checkbox2,
.checkbox3,
.checkbox4 {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code. Please check this link:http://jsfiddle.net/5V288/1539/

```
    var icheckBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]'); 
    icheckBoxes.each(function(index){  
    if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {                                      
    $('.checkbox'+index).css('outline','2px solid #c00');
    }
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);   
    });
```